# How to get value of array by checking its value

Tags: php, arrays

How can i get the object which has the value of `[existence] == 1`

If `[existence] == 1` I want to get all the object that has `[existence] == 1`

and remove all `[existence] == 0`

This is my array .

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [accountcode_naisen] => 
            [extentype] => 0
            [extenrealname] => 
            [name] => 0090000270
            [extenktaiemail] => 
            [secret] => Myojyo42_f
            [username] => 0090000270
            [guestIpAddr] => 192.168.236.15
            [participantSetting] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [existence] => 1
                    [leader] => 1
                    [simultaneous] => 
                )

        )

)
```

This is my code so far

```
 foreach ($participants as $participant=>$c) {

            if ($c['existence'] != 1) {
              unset($participants[$participant]);
            }

          }
```

and i am getting this error message **********

> `[30-Sep-2015 15:42:38] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant
>   participantSetting - assumed 'participantSetting' in index.php on line
>   253`

Comment: The error message only says that you used `participantSetting` like a constant but maybe should have used it like a string `'participantSetting'`. Please note the quotes. The rest of your posted code looks ok for me and should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something more efficient than a loop. You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with an anonymous function as callback. Something like this

```
$participants = array_filter(
    $participants,
    function($element) { return $element['participantSetting']['existence'] == 1; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is working

```
foreach ($participants as $participant=>$c) {

   if ($c['participantSetting']['existence'] != 1) {
          unset($participants[$participant]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code might help you..

```
foreach ($participants as $key => &$participant)
{    
     if ($participant['existence'] != 1)
     {
          unset($participant[$key]);
     }    
}
```

When you print the array after the above iteration you will get your expected output.

Comment: Somehow the relation between `$key => &$participant` and `unset($participant[$key]);` is wrong. Also if you're using `as $key => $value` you don't need the reference...